# Calling RACSubject's sendNext inside RACSignal subscriber not working

Tags: objective-c, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

As the title says, calling sendNext on a subject inside the RACSignal that subscribed to the RACSubet does nothing. Nothing fires.  I've verified a second subscriber always receives sendNext values, just not the one where the call is made inside subscribe.

**Code:**

Setup

```
loginStateSubject = [RACSubject subject];
loginStateSignal = [loginStateSubject replayLast];
[loginStateSubject sendNext:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:LOGIN_IDLE]];
```

Subscriber

```
[[loginStateSignal takeWhileBlock:^BOOL(NSNumber *state) {
    if ([state intValue] == LOGGING_IN) {
        NSLog(@"Login state is in LOGGING_IN. Complete subscriber.");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}] subscribeNext:^(NSNumber *state) {
    if ([state intValue] == LOGIN_IDLE) {
        NSLog(@"Login Idle. Attempt login.");
        [loginStateSubject sendNext:[NSNumber numberWithInt:LOGGING_IN]];
        [self loginWithParse];           
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Log out in process while attempting to log in.");
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I hate to answer my own questions but I found the solution. For some reason the subscribeOn and observeOn needed to be defined. I assumed they would default to the current thread, in my case main thread, but seems they needed something specific.

Answer:

```
[[[[loginStateSignal 
subscribeOn:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]]
deliverOn:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]]
takeWhileBlock:^BOOL(NSNumber *state) {
    if ([state intValue] == LOGGING_IN) {
        NSLog(@"Login state is in LOGGING_IN. Complete subscriber.");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}] subscribeNext:^(NSNumber *state) {
    if ([state intValue] == LOGIN_IDLE) {
        NSLog(@"Login Idle. Attempt login.");
        [loginStateSubject sendNext:[NSNumber numberWithInt:LOGGING_IN]];
        [self loginWithParse];           
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Log out in process while attempting to log in.");
    }
}];
```